# Heartbeat with virtual IP at Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking, ip

I have installed heartbeat package at both linux devices so that when ever clients request a service they will be arrived to this IP, and client will not know what are the back-end/actual ip addresses of the nodes. (this is know as virtual-ip or floating-ip)

To enable this feature does each of both devices have two ethernet cards (etho and eth1)?

In many documents I have found there are two eth interfaces are configured?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have configured hearbeat system with one ethernet card on each devices. Using private ethenert card (isolated from wlan) for hearbeat makes system more secure and rebust. Especially connecting of device ethernet cards via cross cable rather than hub would be better.

Answer (score 0):

you need not have 2 ethernet card.For example You can configure your single ethernet card for two ip's using command
**ifconfig eth0:1 ip-address netmask**, so in this ip assigned to eth0 is your original ip address and eth1 ip address is youe virtual ip address. Same concept will be applied to your heartbeat configuration.